# How can you trigger the jquery datepicker function in Struts?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-datepicker

I would like to trigger an event in jquery datepicker ,but when i select a particular date ,its not been triggered.

This is my code for validation of the from date and to date, what should I do to make this function active?

```
$("#fromDate").datepicker({            
    numberOfMonths: 1,
    onselect: function (selected) {
        alert("hello");
        var dt = new Date(selected);
        dt.setDate(dt.getDate() + 1);
        $("#toDate").datepicker("option", "minDate", dt);
    }
});

$("#toDate").datepicker({
    numberOfMonths: 1,
    onselect: function (selected) {
        var dt = new Date(selected);
        dt.setDate(dt.getDate() - 1);
        $("#fromDate").datepicker("option", "maxDate", dt);         
    }
});
```

Comment: Can you please create a sample in http://jsfiddle.net?

Comment: Are you using the default jQuery-UI Datepicker?

Comment: yes using the default jQuery-UI Datepicker

Comment: This is what i wanted ,but for me its not working!!!!       http://aspforums.net/Threads/721888/jQuery-DatePicker-Start-Date-should-be-less-than-End-date-validation/Demos/1

Answer (score 1):

You have to write the function properly. It's onSelect, with an uppercase 'S'

Comment: actually i have written uppercase S only,still not working ,since i am new to jquery datepicker, i would like to know when the function is triggered,as soon as date is been selected??

Comment: Yes, it should be triggered, as soon as you select a date

Answer (score 1):

It's working as you expected, with jQuery-ui datepicker

```js
var $from = $("#fromDate"),
  $to = $("#toDate");
$from.datepicker({
  numberOfMonths: 1,
  onSelect: function(selected) {
    alert("hello");
    var dt = new Date(selected);
    dt.setDate(dt.getDate() + 1);
    $to.datepicker("option", "minDate", dt);
  }
});

$to.datepicker({
  numberOfMonths: 1,
  onSelect: function(selected) {
    var dt = new Date(selected);
    dt.setDate(dt.getDate() - 1);
    $from.datepicker("option", "maxDate", dt);
  }
});
```

```html
<link href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="fromDate" />
<input type="text" id="toDate" />
```

Comment: which browser are you using ? also check there any error in your console

Comment: It's working in my chrome browser without any problem

Comment: Here is my textfield of fromdate,using struts  :                           <s:textfield cssClass="datepicker" value="%{formattedDate}" disabled="true" id="fromDate" name="fromDate" onselect="validationdates()" placeholder="  FROM DATE" onchange="hidevalidations()">                                                       <s:date id="formattedDate" name="PRESET_Date" format="MM/dd/yyyy"/>
                </s:textfield>

Comment: I think its the problem with the struts,because when i removed all the struts properties and just given the normal text box with id "fromdate " and "todate".its working now!!!

Comment: @Coder : i don't knows about struts :)